# javascript month calculator not working

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following code. It is an automatic month generator. If i click submit, the value is getting stored as **NOVEMBER** in the database. But I want it to be saved as **11**.Help me.

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        $month=$_POST['month'];
        $total=$_POST['total'];
        $points=$_POST['points'];
        $lotsize=$_POST['lotsize'];
        $amount=$_POST['amount'];

        $sql = 'INSERT INTO total(id,month,total,points,lotsize,amount) VALUES("'.$id.'","'.$month.'","'.$total.'","'.$points.'","'.$lotsize.'","'.$amount.'")';
        $msg="<p style=\"color:#3366FF; font-size:13px;\"> Successfull!</p>";
        if (!mysql_query($sql, $con))
        {
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>

        alert('Details Submitted');

        </script>";
    }
?>

<select id="month" name="month"><option value=""><?php echo date('F') ?></option>
    <option value="1">January</option><?php if($month == "january"){echo "checked";} ?>
    <option value="2">February</option><?php if($month == "february"){echo "checked";} ?>
    <option value="3">March</option><?php if($month == "march"){echo "checked";} ?>
    <option value="4">April</option><?php if($month == "april"){echo "checked";} ?>
    <option value="5">May</option><?php if($month == "may"){echo "checked";} ?>
    <option value="6">June</option><?php if($month == "june"){echo "checked";} ?>
    <option value="7">July</option><?php if($month == "july"){echo "checked";} ?>
    <option value="8">August</option><?php if($month == "august"){echo "checked";} ?>
    <option value="9">September</option><?php if($month == "september"){echo "checked";} ?>
    <option value="10">October</option><?php if($month == "october"){echo "checked";} ?>
    <option value="11">November</option><?php if($month == "November"){echo "checked";} ?>
    <option value="12">December</option><?php if($month == "december"){echo "checked";} ?>
</select>
```

Comment: provide your php code

Comment: This is my php code. It is getting stored as month name.But I want as month number

Comment: This is what we call HTML. PHP is the code that checks the value and sends it to the database. Are you aware November is the only capitalized month in your system?

Comment: <?php 
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
     {
$id=$_POST['id'];
$month=$_POST['month'];
$total=$_POST['total'];
$points=$_POST['points'];
$lotsize=$_POST['lotsize'];




$sql = 'INSERT INTO total(id,month,total,points,lotsize) VALUES("'.$id.'","'.$month.'","'.$total.'","'.$points.'","'.$lotsize.'")';
            $msg="<p style=\"color:#3366FF; font-size:13px;\"> Successfull!</p>";
   if (!mysql_query($sql, $con))
   {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
   }
    
    
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
   
      alert('Details Submitted');
    
     </script>";
 
}
?>

Comment: can you add it to your question?

Comment: your code looks fine, must be something else interfering. Once you have it working with numbers instead of names you will have to adjust your `<select></select>` code because it is comparing with names now. Did you write this code, or did you copy it from somewhere?

Comment: Is this all one file? Where is `$month` set when `$submit` isn't set?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your HTML code, you are using `checked` which should be used for check boxes and radio buttons, not drop down menus.

Also you are using `if($month == "November")` if you want `$month` to be stored as 11 wouldn't that be `if($month == "11")`?

So I believe your final code will look like:

```
<select id="month" name="month">
    <option value=""><?php echo date('F') ?></option>
    <option value="1" <?php if ($month == "1") echo 'selected' ?>>January</option>
    <option value="2" <?php if ($month == "2") echo 'selected' ?>>February</option>
    <option value="3" <?php if ($month == "3") echo 'selected' ?>>March</option>
    <option value="4" <?php if ($month == "4") echo 'selected' ?>>April</option>
    <option value="5" <?php if ($month == "5") echo 'selected' ?>>May</option>
    <option value="6" <?php if ($month == "6") echo 'selected' ?>>June</option>
    <option value="7" <?php if ($month == "7") echo 'selected' ?>>July</option>
    <option value="8" <?php if ($month == "8") echo 'selected' ?>>August</option>
    <option value="9" <?php if ($month == "9") echo 'selected' ?>>September</option>
    <option value="10" <?php if ($month == "10") echo 'selected' ?>>October</option>
    <option value="11" <?php if ($month == "11") echo 'selected' ?>>November</option>
    <option value="12" <?php if ($month == "12") echo 'selected' ?>>December</option>
</select>
```